# Delete contents from tables specified by user

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to delete the contents of some tables. I want the user to select the table names and these are concatenated to a string. eg: `Brands,Products,ProductGroups` this string is passed to the stored procedure `DBReset`. I have a function to split the string and return the values as a table. It works fine. Now I want to delete the contents of the 3 tables (excluding contents with branchID =0) returned from the function called `Split`.
Here is what I have tried:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DBReset

        (@Tables varchar(200))
AS
BEGIN
DELETE FROM (SELECT Items FROM [dbo].[Split] (@Tables, ',')) WHERE BranchID<>0
END
```

Which gives error:

```
Incorrect syntax near '('.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.
```

Then I tried dynamic sql:

```
EXEC('DELETE FROM (SELECT Items FROM [dbo].[Split] ('+@Tables+', '','')) WHERE BranchID<>0')
```

It gives the same error when executing.
Is there any possible way to do this? Thanks for sharing your valuable time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### APPROACH 1:

You cannot delete from multiple tables from a single query (Unless you have a foreign key constraint between your tables and activate the "cascade delete" option on the constraint)

In your case, the most simple approach would be to replace the comma as shown below and use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @CONDITION VARCHAR(255)
SET @CONDITION = ' WHERE BRANCHID <> 0; DELETE FROM '

SET @TABLELIST = 'DELETE FROM ' + REPLACE(@Tables,',',@CONDITION)+' WHERE BRANCHID <> 0;'
EXEC (@TABLELIST)
```

### APPROACH 2:

If you are going to use the split function approach, you need to return the Table Names in the split function & can use dynamic SQL:

1. Create function to return Table Names:

   ```
   CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SPLIT_FUNTION(
   @SINPUTLIST VARCHAR(MAX) -- Your data to be split
   , @SDELIMITER VARCHAR(5000) = ',' -- The Delimited that is used for splitting
   ) RETURNS @TABLELIST TABLE (TABLE_NAMES VARCHAR(5000))

   BEGIN
   DECLARE @ITEMLIST VARCHAR(MAX)
   WHILE CHARINDEX(@SDELIMITER,@SINPUTLIST,0) <> 0
   BEGIN
   SELECT
   @ITEMLIST=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@SINPUTLIST,1,CHARINDEX(@SDELIMITER,@SINPUTLIST,0)-1))),
   @SINPUTLIST=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@SINPUTLIST,CHARINDEX(@SDELIMITER,@SINPUTLIST,0)+LEN(@SDELIMITER),LEN(@SINPUTLIST))))

   IF LEN(@ITEMLIST) > 0
   INSERT INTO @TABLELIST SELECT @ITEMLIST
   END

   IF LEN(@SINPUTLIST) > 0
   INSERT INTO @TABLELIST SELECT @SINPUTLIST

   RETURN

   END
   ```
2. Form & execute delete statement:

   ```
   DECLARE @DELETE_STATEMENT VARCHAR(MAX)  
   SELECT @DELETE_STATEMENT =  COALESCE(@DELETE_STATEMENT + ' WHERE BRANCHID <> 0 ; ', '') + 'DELETE FROM '+ TABLE_NAMES FROM DBO.SPLIT_FUNTION(@TABLES,',')
   EXEC (@DELETE_STATEMENT) -- DELETE
   ```

Comment: Accepting this answer since the approach 1 seems simpler.

Answer (score 0):

you will most likely need to iterate over the result set from the split, and then use exec to execute the sql with the table in the scope of the current iteration of the loop, adding in your where clause as you go.

you can do this via a cursor, or within a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Here the code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DBReset

        (@Tables varchar(200))
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @TableName as varchar(30)
DECLARE CSR CURSOR
FOR
(SELECT Items FROM [dbo].[Split] (@Tables, ','))
OPEN CSR
FETCH NEXT FROM CSR INTO @TableName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN
        EXEC('DELETE FROM '+@TableName+' WHERE BranchID<>0')
        FETCH NEXT FROM CSR INTO @TableName
    END
CLOSE CSR
DEALLOCATE CSR
END
```

Works like charm. Thanks for Adam Grande for showing the stepping stones.
NOTE: Accepting AJJ's answer since the approach 1 seems simpler.